# Why does the Spring csrf give me a 403 network error?

Tags: spring-security, csrf

My apologies for the messy HTML syntax below.  When I have the `http.authorizeRequest()` csrf enabled,  I keep getting a 403 error.  Of course, if I have `csrf.disable()`, everything works fine.

It is my understanding that the `<form:form>` tag automatically used the CSRF token, which must be the case because the URL below stops working.

Can someone tell me what it is that I don't understand?

> NetworkError: 403 Forbidden - http://localhost:8080/AssetCore/createGuideline/

My Configuration class:

```java
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{
    private final Logger log = Logger.getLogger (this.getClass());
    /**
     * This class gets called during startup.
     */

    /**
     * Configure http security.
     */
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        /**
         * This method gets called when the app starts up.
         * I believe that all the patterns for the MVC and rest calls will need to go here.
         */
        log.info("configure(): called to set up authorizedRequest pattern matching.");
        http
            .logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/login?loggedout=true").invalidateHttpSession(true).deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
            .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"));
        http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.PUT, "/assessment/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/createGuideline/**",).permitAll()    
    }
```

The JSP:

```
   <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="sec" uri="http://www.springframework.org/security/tags"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="ark" tagdir="/WEB-INF/tags" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type"
            content="text/html; charset=windows-1252">
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>ASSET Core - PCC</title>
        <jsp:include page="ourCSSandJS.jsp" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/AssetCore/resources/css/pccStyle.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/AssetCore/resources/css/scrollbar.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/AssetCore/resources/css/mcp_style.css">
        <script>var storedFormatExtraArgs = [];</script>
        <script src="/AssetCore/resources/js/valid/pcc.js"></script>
        <script src="/AssetCore/resources/js/controlFormatting.js"></script>
        <script src="/AssetCore/resources/js/valid/controlCard.js"></script>
        <script src="/AssetCore/resources/js/thirdParty/jquery.scrollbar.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>     
    </head>
    <body>`                     <form:form id="customGuide" method="POST"
                            action="/AssetCore/createGuideline">
                            <fieldset>
                                <legend id="createGuideline">Create Guideline</legend>
                                <p>
                                    <label for="gName">Name</label><br /> <input type="text"
                                        id="gName" name="gName" />
                                </p>`
```

Comment: At first glance, it should work.  Try it in Chrome, and look in the network inspector to see if the csrf token is in the form post.

Comment: I don't think it is.  This is what I got: Request URL:http://localhost:8080/AssetCore/createGuideline/
Request Method:POST
Status Code:403 Forbidden
Remote Address:[::1]:8080
Response Headers
view source
Cache-Control:no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Content-Language:en-US
Content-Length:2106
Content-Type:text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1
Date:Fri, 16 Sep 2016 19:14:44 GMT
Expires:0
Pragma:no-cache
Server:Apache-Coyote/1.1
X-Content-Type-Options:nosniff
X-Frame-Options:DENY
X-XSS-Protection:1; mode=block
Request Headers

Comment: That's the response headers (I think), unless I'm misreading the docs it would be in the request body.

Comment: I added the following coded <form:form id="customGuide" method="POST"
                            action="/AssetCore/createGuideline" onsubmit="return showValue();"> and the javascript function to alert with he value which returned "undefined".  So it <form:form> is not injecting it.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so the Spring documentation isn't correct, at least not what I saw.  I actually added the following to the `<form:form>` tag

```
<input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}" />
```

And now it works.